# Auto allocate resources

Tags: ms-project, resource-planning

Is there any way to make MS project choose the resources for tasks between candidates that I've given to it? I mean there are several people who can do a task but how many of them and which ones are efficient for the project.
In other words is MS project able to level resources by allocating them and postponing tasks leading to an efficient result?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Assign Resources Automatically in the Most Efficient Manner](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/25797/assign-resources-automatically-in-the-most-efficient-manner)

Comment: Please clarify.  Your first question asks for automatic skill-based resource assignment, which MS Project does NOT do.  Your second question, "In other words...?" is a completely different summary of resource leveling delay, which MS Project DOES do.